# Remove all sites from allowed list for plugin in IE via GP

Tags: group-policy, java, internet-explorer, flash

I would like to remove all sites from the list of approved sites for a plugin in Internet Explorer [as described here](http://www.howtogeek.com/188059/how-to-enable-click-to-play-plugins-in-every-web-browser/) but I would like to do so via Group Policy. Is this possible?

I know I can [disable plugins via Group Policy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11406.how-to-disable-internet-explorer-ie-add-ons-through-group-policy.aspx), but I need to leave the plugins enabled and available for users, I just want to force the users to allow the plugin to run if they want to see the content instead of allowing it run by default.

Answer (score 0):

This is gross.  I used ProcMon to trace the individual change in the registry for Shockwave Flash Player. I saw the following path contained the domain list changes:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Ext\Stats\{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11CF-96B8-444553540000}\iexplore\AllowedDomains\*
```

That GUID is for the particular version of Shockwave Flash Player installed on my system.  I could not tell if you if that is valid for every flavor of this add-in.

Unless your add-in has it's own Group Policy extensions (ADMX + ADML), I'm not sure how you could go about administratively managing this list reliably.

Comment: Check this out, that key applies to "Shock wave Flash" in general: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737898(v=ws.10).aspx You could probably use that key as a reliable place for your settings because of this. Though, as with all things GP related, test it thoroughly! Also: beware of tattooing.